# Send and Receive Data over IP address vb.net application

Tags: vb.net, tcp

I have an application that sends and receives data Over COM port 
this is the code for receiving data:

```
Private Sub ReceivedText(ByVal [text] As String) 'input pentru citire readexisting
    If Me.rtbComData.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim x As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf ReceivedText)
        Me.Invoke(x, New Object() {(text)})
    Else
        Me.rtbComData.Text &= [text] 'adauga text
        Me.rtbComData.BackColor = Color.Green
    End If
End Sub



Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
    ReceivedText(SerialPort1.ReadExisting())
End Sub
```

And this is the code for sending data.

```
SerialPort1.WriteLine("AT+DSCAN")
```

All I need is to send this kind of data over IP.

I need to connect to specific IP and send data, and then use the response to full a rich text box.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials about using sockets to communicate over TCP/IP. I would suggest working through a few.

Comment: trust me i did that..but it seems that i m going mad trying to figure it out . i;ll try somme more and then i will see.. thank you for the keyword